# Ideal way of showing context sensitive help on partial view load in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an application with several partial views, some are loaded via ajax, some are not.

There are some context sensitive notes for each of these partial views stored in the database.

When each of these partial views load, I want to load their help text inside a div and show it on a side bar.

I want to do this with minimal rewrite of existing partial views.

Some of the approaches I have considered

1) Add a layout to all partial views. Add a data-helpText attribute to all divs encapsulating a partial view. In the layout page, on document.ready, I will read the data-helpText attribute and fire off an ajax query to load the help text from the database.

2) Add a helptext attribute to the viewbag of each partial view. Read this attribute and fire off an ajax query to read help text. Problem with this approach is the next partial view will overwrite the attribute. Is there any way I could create a collection in viewbag and dynamically append to this from each partial view ?

Neither of the above approaches seem all that great to me. Has anyone else done something like this or has an idea on what approach I should take ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you but you could try the following : Any time you load a partial view reload the sidebar div with ajax? That ajax call would post a list of partialview id's that are currently open on the page to a controller. The controller would read db grabbing whatever views are opened' contexts and re-render the sidebar.

Comment: @mwwallace8 This is possibly the way to go, but how do I know the ids of all the partial views that are rendered in the page ?

Comment: I think just add a div with the same class on each partial and also have a data-id or an id saying which one each is. Then use jQuery and do $('.partialClass').each to loop through and add the id's to some sort of array variable or list you post.

Comment: @mwwallace8 I think that is the approach I would take. One problem I have is inside a view, some partial views will be loaded via ajax, some will be loaded from the server side code. I dont have an event to capture when all the partial views are loaded. I guess I will have to write something  along those lines. I really appreciate with your pointers. Thanks

Comment: No problem sir. I figure you would do your new sidebarLoader function once on document.ready then again after each ajax call? Good luck!